# PHP: post today's date from a form to a text file

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, post

I created a form in html and the inputs are posted to a text file with PHP. I want to add a date stamp when the inputs are submitted to the text file. With my code, it doesn't print out the date.

php file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$file = "loginRequest.txt";

$company_name = $_POST['Company_name'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$account_num = $_POST['Account_num'];
$address = $_POST['Address'];
$city = $_POST['City'];
$state = $_POST['State'];
$zip = $_POST['Zip'];
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
$date = $_POST['todayDate'];


$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

$email_message = "Form details below.\r\n";

$email_message .= "First Name: $first_name\r\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: $last_name\r\n";
$email_message .= "Account#: $account_num\r\n";
$email_message .= "Address: $address\r\n";
$email_message .= "City: $city\r\n";
$email_message .= "State: $state\r\n";
$email_message .= "Zip: $zip\r\n";
$email_message .= "Email: $email_from\r\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: $telephone\r\n";
$email_message .= "Company Name: $company_name\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fopen($file, "a") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");
fwrite($fp, $email_message) or die("Couldn't write values to file!");

fclose($fp);
?>
```

my form in html:

```
 <!-- WORK IN PROGRESSS: this is the hidden input for the date stamp-->
 <tr>
 <td>
 <input type="hidden" name="startdate" id="todayDate"/>
 </td>
 </tr>
```

Javascript logic to get the date:

```
<!-- hidden date stamp logic -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function getDate(){
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm}
today = yyyy+""+mm+""+dd;

document.getElementById("todayDate").value = today;
};

//call getDate() when loading the page
getDate();
```

Comment: um.. you have `todayDate` as the POST array name here, not `startdate` and there's no input of that name.

Answer (score 0):

Change $_POST['todayDate']; to $_POST['startdate'];

Also you have nothing that actually prints the date so that you could see it. You'll need to add:

```
$email_message .= "Date: $date\r\n";
```